# php preg_match nightmare

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I just cant get my head around regex, any help appreciated !

I have plenty of string data which may or may not contain the strings "1/10" or "2/10" or "2/18" etc. Basically, both the numerators and denominators could vary. And to make things more complex, some of the data entry operators **may** have put a space anywhere between the numerators and denominators !! 
So my inputs could be :
"x/y" or "x / y" or "x/ y" or "x /y" or "x/y " .... and probably more combos :(

In any of these cases, I wish to identify if x and y are numbers, and if there is a "/" slash between them. Am hopeless at regex, please help

Am coding in php and I guess preg_match is what needs to be used.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: http://www.phpvideotutorials.com/regex/

Comment: Check out some of the tools listed in [Open source RegexBuddy alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) which might help you getting started and designing regexpressions.

Comment: would 1.2/4.2 have to match also?

Comment: no Hamish, Luckily I get no fractions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$pattern = "%(\d+) */ *(\d+)%";

$test = array(
    'half is 1/2',
    '13/100 is your score',
    'only 23 /90 passed',
    'no idea here:7/ 123',
    '24 / 25',
    '1a/2b'
);

foreach($test as $t){
    if(preg_match($pattern, $t, $matches))
        echo "PASS: n:$matches[1], d:$matches[2]\n";
    else
        echo "FAIL: $t\n";
}
```

outputs:

```
PASS: n:1, d:2
PASS: n:13, d:100
PASS: n:23, d:90
PASS: n:7, d:123
PASS: n:24, d:25
FAIL: 1a/2b
```

Comment: brilliant, works perfect ! and thats a cool test case you gave :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if(preg_match('~^[0-9]+\s*/\s*[0-9]+$~',trim($subject))) {
  // valid
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but only if my string contains nothing other than a x/y variant.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match('@^\s?[0-9]+\s?\/\s?[0-9]+\s?$@', $s) {
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but only if my string contains nothing other than a x/y variant.

Comment: To make it match any string that contains an x/y variant, remove the `^` and `$`. They mean - start of string and end of string respectively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid regexp at any cost. A couple of cases you should(could):

- You are an expert in regexp. If you are you, then probably you should use regexp because it probably is going to be faster and terser code. Although the readability is going to suck in my opinion.
- You need to improve performance.

Otherwise my advice is to not use it!

> In any of these cases, I wish to
>   identify if x and y are numbers, and
>   if there is a "/" slash between them.
>   Am hopeless at regex, please help

How to solve your problem:

```
<?php

class Verify {
    public static function numbers($str) {
        $explode = explode("/", $str);

        foreach($explode as $elm) {
            if (!filter_var($elm, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testBothPartsAreNumbers() {
        $array = array(
            "1/2",
            "1 / 2",
            "1/ 2",
            "1 /2"
        );
        foreach($array as $elm) {
            $this->assertTrue(Verify::numbers($elm));
        }
    }

    public function testOneOfThemMightBeNotANumber() {
        $array = array(
            "1/a",
            "a/1",
            "1 / a",
            "b/2",
            "b/a",
            "1/2.1",
        );
        foreach($array as $elm) {
            $this->assertFalse(Verify::numbers($elm));
        }
    }
}
?>
```

---

```
alfred@alfred-laptop:~/php/stackoverflow/4916920$ php -v
PHP 5.3.3-1ubuntu9.3 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jan 12 2011 16:08:14) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2010, by Derick Rethans

# We need at least PHP5.2 for filter.

alfred@alfred-laptop:~/php/stackoverflow/4916920$ phpunit NumberTest.php 
PHPUnit 3.5.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

..

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 3.50Mb

OK (2 tests, 10 assertions)
```